# Putting a JavaScript variable in PHP array

Tags: javascript, php

I was making an image gallery with up and down buttons ,the array $imageids contains all image ids. I want to access these values with 
JavaScript as follows,

**PHP :**

```
require"./connect.php";
$imgquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM press INNER JOIN subscriptions ON     press.userid=subscriptions.to_u WHERE subscriptions.from_u='30' ORDER BY  press.id DESC ");
$countrow = mysql_num_rows($imgquery);
$imageids = array();
while($fimgq = mysql_fetch_assoc($imgq)) {
    $imgid = $fimgq['id'];
    array_push($imageids,$imgid);
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = -1;
    var cr = <?php echo $countrow ?>;
    $('#down').click(function() {
        if (i < cr-1) {
            i = i + 1;
            var ard = <?php echo $imageids[i]?>;
            alert(ard);
        }
    }); 
    $('#up').click(function() {
        if(i>0) {
            i = i - 1;
            var aru = <?php echo $imageids[i]?>;
            alert(aru);
        }
    }); 
});
```

I want to get `$imageids` elements by putting a javascript variable i inside `$imageids[]` array , like

```
var ard = <?php echo $imageids[i]?>;
alert(ard); // Which doesn't work
```

Comment: PHP generates javascript. It isn't available once the page has loaded. Output the PHP array to the javascript then itterate through it in JS.

Comment: @chris85 is right. PHP is server-side, JavaScript (in this case) is client-side. Once you're running JavaScript, the PHP has already been rendered to HTML. and the request to the server is finished.

Answer (score 0):

As @chris85 and @Khalos pointed out in comments, the PHP variables are all dead once the JavaScript runs, so you need to output all the ID:s into an JavaScript array. It would looke something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var i=-1;
  var cr= <?php echo $countrow ?>;

  //Save all the ID:s to a JS variable so they can be used later.
  var imageids = [<?php echo implode(',', $imageids); ?>];

  $('#down').click(function(){
    if(i<cr-1) {
      i=i+1;
      alert(imageids[i]); //This uses the JS variable imageids, not the dead PHP one.
    }
  });    

  $('#up').click(function(){
    if(i>0) {
      i=i-1;
      alert(imageids[i]); //Same as above.
    }
  }); 

});
```